# How to write the output of the program to a excel sheet

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to enter the output of the program to an excel sheet/

**I have tried using Apache POI**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Ex3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDir = new File("C:\\Myfiles\\Script"); // current directory
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        try {

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("folder:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    displayDirectoryContents(file);
                } else {
                System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to enter the output of the if statement to 1st column and output of else to 2nd column or both in separate sheets which ever is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always create this same method regardless of my needs and then adapt the input for it

```
public static void printAtFile(String filename, String header, String content[])
    {
        System.out.println("Start creating file "+filename);
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(filename);
            writer.println(header);
            for(String u:content)
                writer.println(u);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while writing at file "+filename);
        }
    }
```

In this case, you want to do something like

```
String h = "Column1,column2"
String content[] = new String[N];
Arrays.fill(content, "");
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if(...)content[i]="whateveryouwant,"+"blank";
    else content[i]="blank,"+"whateveryouwant";
}
printAtFile("file.csv",h,content);
```